# How does a flexible CNC coupler work?

Tags: coupling

[image]

I'm talking about this one. On what principle does it work? The only thing i can think of is that you press the shaft with the screws and then it works based on friction but I have no idea if it is correct.

Comment: What sort of flexing do you expect? Do you think this might be to reduce vibration?

Comment: I don't expect any flexing, just wondering on what basis does the input shaft turn the coupling.

Comment: By the helix...

Comment: You don't understand my question... why doesn't the motor shaft just spin inside the coupling? What connects the shaft and the coupling?

Answer (score 2):

Those four screws are usually tightened against a flat or flats machined on the two shafts.

That prevents any slipping and possible damage to either shaft.